# FragmentActivity: cannot resolve setContentView

Tags: android-fragments, resolve, setcontentview

I'm having the problem that for the following activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements UpdateActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabbed_main_activity); <-- error here
```

I get the follwoing error: `Cannot resolve method setContentView(int)`

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I also cross checked with http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: R.layout.tabbed_main_activity, have you got this in your xml folders. it looks like you cant compile it happens when you have error in the code. or simply some files are named wrong or missing

Comment: Murat, thanks for your answer. I compiled it and it works fine. However, the ide (android studio) continues to display errors. Anybody got an idea why the idea keeps telling me that this method does not exist?